# Backbonejs - How can I print the results of a fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, dto

Hi I'm new to Backbone and I was just playing around with it a little, here is my code:

```
    var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
        url : 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users'
    });

    var users = new Users();
    users.fetch({
        success: function () {
            console.log(users);
        }
    });
```

The fetch call succeeds and I am returned with an object that looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "hqel839m1071rbggsxf7",
    "firstname": "Thomas",
    "lastname": "Davis",
    "age": 12
  }
]
```

How can I print different parts of the result?
For example I want to print the "id" parameter of the first item. Can I iterate it like an array?

I tried to do `console.log(users[0].id)` but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are three different ways to access the models in a `Backbone.Collection`.  First, you can use the `.get` method to find a model based on it's unique ID.  This basically looks at all models in the collection and compares their `id` attribute to the one provided.

```
var user = collection.get('unique_id'); // return an instance, or null
```

The second method is to use the `.at` method to get a model by index.  This is useful if your models are sorted.  If they are not sorted, they'll be fetched by insertion order (that is, the order in which they were provided to the collection):

```
var user = collection.at(0); // return the first model in the collection
```

Lastly, you can access the raw array of models that the Collection wraps.  You can access this via the `.models` attribute, which is just an array.  This is not the recommended approach.

```
var user = collection.models[0];
```

Once you have a user, you can access any attributes of the user via the `.get` method on your model:

```
var age = user.get("age");
user.set("age", 100);
```

You can view the documentation for the model `get` method [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get), and the documentation for `Backbone.Collection` [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection).

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined " when I try to do console.log(users[0].get("id"));

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my answer, I forgot about the models array. What I linked will now work.

Answer (score 3):

Not to forget about the `arguments` passed to `success` callback of `collection.fetch` which are `(collection, response, options)`. Check documentation [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch). You can use the `collection` argument to select a particular `model`. Check below code :

```
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    url : 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users'
});

var users = new Users();
users.fetch({
    success: function (collection, response, options) {
        //Will log JSON objects of all User objects
        console.log(collection.toJSON());
        //You can get a Model using 'id'
        var user = collection.get("hqesig1ea1br2k6horay");
        // Will log User Model for id "hqesig1ea1br2k6horay"
        console.log(user);
        //You can then fetch Model attributes this way
        console.log("ID: ", user.get('id'));
        console.log("First name: ", user.get('firstname'));
        console.log("Lastname : ", user.get('lastname'));
    }
});
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/d78Kt/) for your reference.